# Determining whether a ring presented by quadratic relations is free abelian

Tags: combinatorics, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring generated by $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ with several relations of the form
$$
[x_i,\sum_{j\in J} x_j]=0
$$
for some set of indices $J$. Note that I really mean just a sum, not an arbitrary linear combination, that $R$ is graded, each generator having degree 1, and that the degree 1 part is the free abelian group on the $x_i$'s.

> Is there an easy criterion to determine whether $R$ is free as an abelian group ?

Comment: And $[ \cdot, \cdot]$ is a commutator, $[a, b] = a b - b a$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have said that ! In fact $R$ is nothing but the enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra with the same generators and relations, so in case it makes things easier.

Comment: I asked this question on MO as well : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263963/mathbb-z-torsion-for-some-quadratic-lie-rings